# flutter: BLoC Builder not updating, though I see new/different state in debugger

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

My 2nd strange event today. When I follow the debugger inside bloc.dart (the library, not my file) and  I see that `transition.nextState == state && _emitted` is `false`, it does not update my widget (nextState has list size 2, state has 10 - _emitted is true). To my understanding the builder should be ok, is there any other spot to look at why it does not update?

Just to explain the logic before I show the code

1. I fetch my data upon app launch with

   ```
   BlocProvider(create: (context) =>
     LogicGraphsPStmntBloc(logicGraphsRepository:
     logicGraphsRepository)..add(LogicGraphsNextProblemRequested()),
   ```
2. this returns a list of 10 strings, which I store in my _bloc.dart file (not sure if this is state of the art)
3. These 10 strings are sent via the state `LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statements)` and are properly rendered as buttons
4. If I click a button, only the 1st and the selected string shall be shown. The event is properly triggered with `onPressed: () {BlocProvider.of<LogicGraphsPStmntBloc>(context).add(LogicGraphsPStmntCollapsed(statement: index-1));},`
5. This properly triggers the state `yield LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statementsShown);` with  now only 2 elements in the list (as compared to 10 in step 3) but it does not cause a rerendering
6. If I step into the state with the debugger, I can see that both states have a different number of elements.

my states

```dart
abstract class LogicGraphsPStmntState extends Equatable {
  const LogicGraphsPStmntState();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess extends LogicGraphsPStmntState {
  const LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess([this.statements = const []]);
  final List<String> statements;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];

  @override
  String toString() => 'LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess { statements: $statements }';
}
```

my bloc (not exactly, because the code inside my sub functions to release a state are not reached as described in [my other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955853/flutter-code-does-not-step-into-function-within-bloc-definition-adaption-of-to). So currently I have those sub functions lines as spaghetti in the mapEventToState=

```dart
class LogicGraphsPStmntBloc extends Bloc<LogicGraphsPStmntEvent, LogicGraphsPStmntState> {
  LogicGraphsPStmntBloc({@required this.logicGraphsRepository}) : super(LogicGraphsPStmntInProgress());
  final LogicGraphsRepository logicGraphsRepository;
  List<String> statements;
  int currentProblem = -1;

  @override
  Stream<LogicGraphsPStmntState> mapEventToState(LogicGraphsPStmntEvent event) async* {
        if (event is LogicGraphsNextProblemRequested) {
          _mapLGPStmntNewProblemRequested();
          _mapLGPStmntLoadRequested(currentProblem);
        }
        else if (event is LogicGraphsPStmntLoadRequested) {
          _mapLGPStmntLoadRequested(currentProblem);
        }
        else if (event is LogicGraphsPStmntCollapsed) {
          _mapLGPStmntCollapseRequested(event);
  }
  Stream<LogicGraphsPStmntState> _mapLGPStmntNewProblemRequested() async* {
        try {
          currentProblem =
          await getNextProblem(currentProblem == null ? -1 : currentProblem);
          statements =
          await logicGraphsRepository.getProblemStmntList(currentProblem);
          _mapLGPStmntLoadRequested(currentProblem);
        } catch (_) {
          yield LogicGraphsPStmntLoadFailure();
        }
  }
  Stream<LogicGraphsPStmntState> _mapLGPStmntLoadRequested(int problem) async* {
          try {
            yield LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statements);
          } catch (_) {
            yield LogicGraphsPStmntLoadFailure();
          }
  }
  Stream<LogicGraphsPStmntState> _mapLGPStmntCollapseRequested(
          LogicGraphsPStmntCollapsed event) async* {
          List<String> statementsShown = [];
          statementFocussed = event.statement;
          statementsShown.add(statements[0]);
          statementsShown.add(statements[statementFocussed]);
          yield LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statementsShown);
  }
}
```

my widgets

```dart
class LogicGraphPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final LogicGraphsRepository logicGraphsRepository = LogicGraphsRepository(
      logicGraphsApiClient: LogicGraphsApiClient());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) =>
        LogicGraphsPStmntBloc(logicGraphsRepository: logicGraphsRepository)
          ..add(LogicGraphsNextProblemRequested()),
          child:BlocBuilder<LogicGraphsPStmntBloc, LogicGraphsPStmntState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess) {
                final List<String> statements = state.statements;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: statements.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return CupertinoButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        child: Text(statements[index])
                        onPressed: () {BlocProvider.of<LogicGraphsPStmntBloc>(context).add(LogicGraphsPStmntCollapsed(statement: index-1));},
                      );
                    });
              }
              else return Container();
            }
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The function inside the bloc.dart library where I would assume that the new state is emitted. You see the line `if (transition.nextState == state && _emitted) return;`. Next state has 2 elements, state has 10, _emitted is true, so I would assume the code to continue. Instead the return is triggered and lines with`emit(transition.nextState);` are skipped.

Any help is highly appreciated, since this is my first experience with BLoC/equatable and flutter in general is also still quite new to me. But I am progressing!

```dart
 void _bindEventsToStates() {
    _transitionSubscription = transformTransitions(
      transformEvents(
        _eventController.stream,
            (event) => mapEventToState(event).map(
              (nextState) => Transition(
            currentState: state,
            event: event,
            nextState: nextState,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ).listen(
          (transition) {
        if (transition.nextState == state && _emitted) return; // <<<<<<<<<<<
        try {
          onTransition(transition);
          emit(transition.nextState);
        } on dynamic catch (error, stackTrace) {
          onError(error, stackTrace);
        }
        _emitted = true;
      },
      onError: onError,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the bloc can't tell the difference between `LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statements)` and `LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statementsShown)` as they are the same state and I think it cannot spot the differences between the different parameters.

So what I suggest to do is this:
before yielding `LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statementsShown)` try to yield a "switching" state like I don't know `LogicGraphsPStmntChangeStatement` before that.
So:

```
yield LogicGraphsPStmntChangeStatement;
yield LogicGraphsPStmntLoadSuccess(statementsShown);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: You are absolutely right! So state change means change of the state and not within the state. So when I debugged this, nextstate == state does not compare the value but the "type" of state. What keeps me wondering: If I fetch data online and a chunk is returned after 2s and some more after 10s, will a loadSuccess state wait for 10s and show all data, will it provide the 1st chunk after 2s and the rest later or stop delivering after 2s (not sure if there is kind of EOF in such transmission)?

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but is there any other way to do this?
I mean is there a way to let bloc know that state has changed because the data inside the state has changed?

Comment: Yes there is a way, check this article out: https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-equatable-its-use-inside-bloc-7d14f3b5479b